# Parsing a file, finding the regular expression and output values

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use Python to parse a large text file. I was able to get the regular expression working with a text editor using regular expression. I'm trying to figure out how to translate that to Python code. Any insight would be appreciated.

File is: `sample2.txt`

```
1234 Street Ave
City, State 03433
1 Beds, 2 Baths, 3456 Sq. Ft.
Price: $10,000 

56789 Street Ave
City, State 03433
2 Beds, 3 Baths, 7891 Sq. Ft.
Price: $11,000
```

Regular expression:

```
(.*)\r(.*)\r^([0-9]+)( Beds, )([0-9]+)( Baths, )([0-9]+)( Sq\. Ft\.)\r^(Price: \$)(\d*),(\d+)
```

Replace:

```
\1,\2,\3,\5,\7,\10\11
```

Result/output to `output.txt`: ignore the rest of the file.

```
1234 Street Ave,City, State 03433,1,2,3456,10000 
56789 Street Ave,City, State 03433,2,3,7891,11000
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

f = open("sample2.txt", "r")
print(f.read())

f1 = re.findall(r"^\w+",f)
```

I'm a bit stuck here how do I get regular expression to output?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/desktop/test1.py", line 7, in <module>
    f1 = re.findall(r"^\w+",f)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 241, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Are the data blocks of the text file consistently separated by two carriage returns?

Comment: `f` is a file object, not a string. The return value of `f.read()` would be a string.

Comment: yes they are separated by two carriage returns

Comment: @mkrieger1 sorry pretty new with python.  how do I modify it so python understands it?

Comment: The pattern seems to work. https://regex101.com/r/ALpIBw/1 Did you try `\r?\n` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that what you are passing as second argument to `re.findall`, `f`, is not a string, as expected. It is a file object.

You can get the contents of the file as a string by using `f.read()`. You already do that, but instead of passing it to `re.findall`, you just print it.

So, save the result of `f.read()` in a variable and use it as argument for `re.findall`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

f = open("sample2.txt", "r")
text = f.read()
print(text)

f1 = re.findall(r"^\w+", text)
```

Comment: that makes sense.  But when I output f1 it shows as empty.  Shouldn't it show at least city or price?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't check the contents of the file or the regular expression you are using. The one that is shown here finds the first word if it's at the beginning of the string. Apparently you have already found a more complex regular expression, but you haven't used it in the example code.

Comment: the complicated RE was what worked for me when I constructed (in a text editor with RE support) it to get the output but I'd settle for just getting the regular f1 = re.findall(r"^\w+", text) to output a value so I know it's working.  Essentially outputting a word that starts a line.

Comment: If the result is empty then the text you are using as input does not start with a word. Maybe there is a line break or a space at the beginning of the file?

Comment: ok that helps.  This works for small files but what is the method to parse a file that is GBs?

Comment: should import os method with awk, sed, grep be used for those sized files?

Comment: The same? What is the problem? This is starting to sound like another question however.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233365/discussion-between-lacer-and-mkrieger1).